# Best way to set up ElasticSearch for searching in each customer's data only

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture

We have a SAAS product where companies create accounts and populate their own private data. We are thinking about using ElasticSearch to allow the customer to search all their own data in our system.

As an example we would have a free text search where the user can type anything and the API would return multiple different types of objects. E.g. they type `John` and the API returns the user object for users matching a first name containing `John`, or an email containing `John`. Or it might also return a team object where the team name matches John (e.g. `John's Team`) etc.

So my questions are:

1. Is ElasticSearch a sensible choice for what we want to do from a
   concept perspective?
2. If we did use ElasticSearch what would be the
   best way to index the data so we can search all data for a
   particular customer? Does each customer have its own index?
3. Are there any hints on how we keep ElasticSearch in sync with the data in the database (DynamoDB)? If we index the data for a customer and then update the data as it changes is it sensible to then also reindex the data on a scheduled basis too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to provide general answers from my own experience with splitted customer data with elastic search:

1. If you want to search through a lot of data really fast, ES is always a really good solution for this - it comes with the cost of an secondary data storage that you will have to keep in sync with your database.
2. You cant have diffrent data types in one index, so the case would be either to create one index per data type and customer (carefull, indices come with an overhead - avoid creating too much with little data in it) - or you create one index per data type and add a property to your data where you then can filter it with e.g. a customer number.
   You will have to [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html) your data as much as possible to benefit from elastic search.
3. As mentioned in 1 you will need to keep both in sync - there are plenty ways too do that. As an example we use a an event driven approach to push critical updates into elasticsearch as soon as possible (carefull: its not SQL - so you will always have some concurrency issues when u need read and write safety). For data that is not highly critical we use jobs that update them regulary. When you index a document with the same id it will get completely updated.

Hope this helps, feel free to asy questions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for sharing your own learnings. Very helpful! Cheers, Joel